# What changes are the Australian Labour Party proposing to negative gearing in 2016?

Tags: policy, australia, alp

The proposed changes to negative gearing have received a lot of attention. Plenty of media and the labour party website does not get directly into the details.

Party website
http://www.alp.org.au/negativegearing

Media
http://www.smh.com.au/federal-politics/political-news/negative-gearing-labor-preparing-ground-for-changes-as-think-tank-proposal-estimates-293b-saving-20150610-ghkpap.html

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, Labor's negative gearing policy is that, effective 1st of July 2017, any potential investor who wishes to take advantage of negative gearing must do so on new properties as opposed to the current system where you can also buy a property from someone and negatively gear it. The methodology behind this proposal is that because investors have been holding on to properties to negatively gear for so long, the resulting housing shortage has made it nearly impossible for first home buyers to purchase a home.